# Match an asynchronous HttpWebResponse to a HttpWebRequest in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, httpwebresponse

I'm doing some tests on the HTTP pipelining feature with C#. Everything works fine but I've got a question.

In a class, I have the following code that allows me to get a HTTPWebRequest asynchronously and handle the response :

```
public void getResponseAsync()
    {
        RequestState rs = new RequestState();
        rs.Request = this.webRequest;  //On ajoute la requete dans l'objet état pour pouvoir le récupérer dans la callback
        IAsyncResult ar = rs.Request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(this.ResponseCallback), rs);      // Appel asynchrone 
    }

    public void ResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        RequestState rs = (RequestState)ar.AsyncState;  //Récupération de l'objet etat 
        HttpWebRequest req = rs.Request;                //Récupération de la requete web (object HttpWebRequest)
        try //Récupération de la réponse Web    
        {
            HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.EndGetResponse(ar); 
            this.incomingBuffer = Helpers.getBufferFromStream(resp.GetResponseStream()); 
            resp.Close();
            this.state = true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            this.state = false;
        }
    }

}
// La classe RequestState est utilise pour transmettre l'objet HttpWebRequest 
// a travers l'appel asynchrone
public class RequestState
{
    public HttpWebRequest Request;

    public RequestState()
    {
        Request = null;
    }
}
```

That snippet works fine, but I do not understand the functionning of c#. I do not understand how C# does to identify the response packet and to associate it to my request? Because in the HTTP specifications, there is no "identificator" in the HTTP response.

So how C# does to match a response with a request? Is it with ack and seq numbers?

Comment: It should be the thread which reads the response. `HTTP` response is recieved by the `async` thread which is invoked on  `IAsyncResult ar = rs.Request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(this.ResponseCallback), rs);` Every async request will have a thread associated with it.

Comment: @abhinav : I agree that it is the async thread which catch the HTTP response. But how C# determines the corresponding thread when a HTTP response arrives?  Because there is nothing in the HTTP response which allows c# to identify a response..

If you have 10 async requests and so 10 threads. When you've got your 10 async responses in a random order, how is it possible for c#  to match each response to the good thread? Is there a number in the request packet?
Thx.

Comment: C# doesn't do the matching. It's handled by the operating system. Remember, those HTTP requests and responses are being transmitted and received via TCP. It's the TCP implementation that matches the low-level responses with the requests, and the asynchronous I/O layer in the operating system matches the TCP stuff with your C# callbacks. That's a simplified explanation, but essentially correct. If you want more detail, you'll have to read up on operating system internals, specifically the implementation of Windows I/O in general and TCP in particular.

Comment: @JimMischel that reads like a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# doesn't do the matching. It's handled by the operating system. Remember, those HTTP requests and responses are being transmitted and received via TCP. It's the TCP implementation that matches the low-level responses with the requests, and the asynchronous I/O layer in the operating system matches the TCP stuff with your C# callbacks.

That's a simplified explanation, but essentially correct. If you want more detail, you'll have to read up on operating system internals, specifically the implementation of Windows I/O in general and TCP in particular.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jim, I also thought about TCP first but when I'm sniffing my application with wireshark, sequence and ack numbers are really weird. I'll double check soon, i'll post my conclusions on this topic. Thanks.